# Classification of zero polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Zero polynomial is a univariate or multivariate polynomial or this  classification is not defined for it?

Comment: Is the empty set a set of integers or a set of polygons?

Comment: Belongs to neither

Comment: So is it to conclude zero polynomial doesn't fit for this classification?

Comment: The symbol 0 is overloaded. Sometimes it refers to the number zero, sometimes it refers to the zero polynomial in $\mathbb R[x]$, sometimes it refers to the zero polynomial in $\mathbb R[x,y]$, etc. Hopefully the meaning is always clear from context

Comment: So why not its better to regard it not define

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $0$ can signify many things. It could mean the natural number $0$, or the real number $0$, or the zero function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, or the zero polynomial in the ring of complex polynomials in the three variables $x,y,z$. And many, many others.

Technically all these $0$'s are different. But their properties are so similar (even in the possible interactions between the algebraic structures mentioned above) that I don't know a single person who makes that difference explicit.

It does have some merit in specific problems and exercises. But then it's mostly because of how it helps the mental bookkeeping and not because of philosophical qualms with this abuse of notation.

Comment: Such bookkeeping concerns also lead to some slightly odd looking definitions, for example the best way to define the degree of the zero polynomial seems to be $-1$.

Comment: @Ian Or $-\infty$, depending on which property of degree you want to preserve.